# Python - Accessing parent class decorators inside class declaration

Tags: python, class, inheritance, decorator

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def some_decorator(cls, ...):
        ...
```

And then I create a subclass which uses the parent class decorator:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    @Foo.some_decorator(...)
    def some_function(...)
        ...
```

How do I remove the need for `Foo.` before the decorator name? The below code doesn't work:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    @some_decorator(...)
    def some_function(...)
        ...
```

I believe this is possible, because the [`sly`](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library does this.

See their example:

```
from sly import Lexer, Parser

class CalcLexer(Lexer):
    ...

    @_(r'\d+')
    def NUMBER(self, t):
        t.value = int(t.value)
        return t

    ...
```

As you can see, you can type in `@_(...)` instead of `@Lexer._(...)`.

How do they accomplish this?

Comment: Aside: I'm not very fond of that design choice. Magically spawning a decorator in the class makes for non-obvious, hard-to-comprehend code. A much cleaner solution would've been to make the user import the `_` decorator with `from sly import _`. Think twice about whether you want to have this in your code base.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That's wouldn't be great too in my opinion: You pollute the global namespace and `_` couldn't mean something different for each class. For sly, `_` has a different meaning for each base class.

Comment: I know nothing about this project, but lexers and parsers are built for speed not readability.  That's why Lex and YACC are so hard for some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass) that implements a [`__prepare__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace) method. Excerpt from the docs:

> 3.3.3.4. Preparing the class namespace
>
> Once the appropriate metaclass has been identified, then the class
>   namespace is prepared. If the metaclass has a `__prepare__` attribute,
>   it is called as `namespace = metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)`
>   (where the additional keyword arguments, if any, come from the class
>   definition).

To put it in simple terms: You make your `__prepare__` method return a dictionary that contains an entry for the decorator. Proof of concept:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __prepare__(name, bases):
        return {'x': 'foobar'}

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    print(x)  # output: foobar
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of making the decorator an `@classmethod` like in my question? I need to access `cls` inside the decorator.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Well, of course it's possible to add `@classmethod` to the decorator, but that won't give it access to the class - it'll just make it crash with `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`. This is a bit difficult to answer in a comment, so could I ask you to post a new question about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207813/python-metaclass-decorator-how-to-use-classmethod

Answer (score 3):

I have looked inside the library you are talking about and the `Lexer` class inherits a metaclass:

`class Lexer(metaclass=LexerMeta):`

Inside the `LexerMeta` you can find the following:

```
@classmethod
    def __prepare__(meta, name, bases):
        d = LexerMetaDict()

        def _(pattern, *extra):
            patterns = [pattern, *extra]
            def decorate(func):
                pattern = '|'.join(f'({pat})' for pat in patterns )
                if hasattr(func, 'pattern'):
                    func.pattern = pattern + '|' + func.pattern
                else:
                    func.pattern = pattern
                return func
            return decorate

        d['_'] = _
        d['before'] = _Before
        return d
```

A metaclass is used to create the class object which then is used to instantiate objects. From what i can see in that method is that here `d['_'] = _` that metaclass dynamically attaches the `_` method to the class you are going to use.

This means that what they are doing is not much different from:

```
class Bar:
    @staticmethod
    def some_decorator(f):
        ...

    @some_decorator
    def some_function(self):
        ...
```